# different text colour for Toggle button

Tags: android

Is there a way to have different text colours for a toggle button? If i use the `android:textColor` attribute, it will be applied to both states of the toggle button. Can we have one colour for `On` and another for `Off`?

Here's an example ToggleButton element :

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:textOn="On"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a directory called `color` under the `res` directory.
In there create an xml file like, `toggle_text_selector.xml`

This is what the file could look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Then on your `ToggleButton` set `android:textColor="@color/toggle_text_selector"`
and you're done